# How to find a linear formula with integer coefficients to split two groups of data?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

For example, I have two groups of data:

group 1:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 22 | 23 |
| 38 | 42 |
| 100 | 200 |

group 2:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 37 | 13 |
| 108 | 5 |

I want to find a linear formula with integer coefficients to distinguish these two groups, for example: group 1 satisfies $y - x + 1 > 0$, group 2 satisfies $y - x + 1 \le 0$
[image]

So how to find this formula? The number of variables could be greater than 2, maybe $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$, and output is the linear formula with integer coefficients like
$$
a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i > 0, \quad a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb Z
$$

The given data make sure the existence of this formula, and I just want to find one of all satisfying formulas.

Comment: Why do you believe such a formula should exist?  What is to prevent some elements from "group 1" to have been placed on the other side.  Even if some formula were to exist, what makes you believe it would be unique?  There could be infinitely many borders which would separate your groups.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to reach for the idea of [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).  I suggest reading more about that topic for the various types and methodologies commonly used in machine learning today.

Comment: Let $A_i$ are points of group 1 and $B_i$ are points of group 2. Let consider all pairs $(A_i,A_j), i\neq j$. Let exclude all pairs such that line $A_iA_j$ divides group 1 (one can check it by computation). Let consider set of all remaining pairs. If for some of remaining pairs all points $B_i$ lie at one side around line $A_jA_k$ then this line can be the answer (or the same line slightly moved to make points $A_j$ and $A_k$ lie at other side than all points $B_i$).

Comment: The given data make sure the existence of this formula, and I just want to find one of all satisfying formulas. @JMoravitz

Comment: Are the $x$ and $y$ values always going to be strictly positive numbers?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier

Comment: You can try to solve your problem using integer programming methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming in which the decision variables are integers. In your case, that will be integer linear programming.

Comment: See also [support vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine)